# Can't get array and sum it up - input is through java dialog

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently trying to figure out how to grab the dialog inputed number by the user and put it in an array in order to count all the numbers to come out with the sum. I currently only need help with the sum not the product towards the bottom. I am only allowed to change what is inside the sums() method.

This is what I had in my sums() so far but it does not display anything when I input. I am supposed to input an infinite number of data and then stop when the user hits 0. The dialog input works but I cant figure out how to do this using the method using a single parameter. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
int sum = 0;
     int counter = 1;

     while(counter > 1) {
       int[] numberArray = new int[counter];
       (numberArray[counter]) = number;
       sum = sum + number;
       System.out.println(sum);
       counter = counter + 1;
     }
     // int counter = 0;
     // int[] numm = new int[counter];
     // (numm[counter]) = number;
```

This is the code with comments:

```
// SumAndProduct.java - This program computes sums and products.
// Input:  Interactive.
// Output:  Computed sum and product.

import javax.swing.*;

public class SumAndProduct
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int number;
      String numberString;

      numberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer or 0 to quit: ");
      number = Integer.parseInt(numberString);

      while(number != 0)
      {
         // call sums() method here
         sums(number);

     // call products() method here
   products(number);

     numberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer or 0 to quit: ");
         number = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
      }

      System.exit(0);

   } // End of main() method.

   // Write sums() method here.
   public static void sums(int number) {
     //sums
   }

   // Write products() method here.
   public static void products(int number) {
     // products
   }

}
// End of SumAndProduct class.
```

Comment: I think, because your `while(counter > 1)` comes never true... You check if `counter` is bigger than one in your while loop, but this condition comes never true because the variable is initialized with 1 and `1 > 1` is **false**...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare two static member to hold the sum and the product so that you can access them from inside the methods.

```
public class SumAndProduct
{
   private static long sum = 0;
   private static long product = 1;

   public static void sums(int number) {
     sum += number;
   }

   public static void products(int number) {
     product *= number;
   }

}
```

Comment: This worked to get my numbers crunching. I will continue the same as much.

Comment: So instead of using an array. Its a simplified dynamic number that gets updated.

Comment: The only way you can hold the value of the sum and product outside the method context is if you hold them in a static member. I don't know whether your array solution will work. I'm assuming you were trying to put all the numbers in an array and them sum them up? Even in that case, the array itself should be declared globally.

Comment: Yes. It would of been a lot more difficult trying to do it my way. I'm learning about these new concepts but my book is very broad and does not give the best examples. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I needed to initialize product in order to get it to work so I set it to 1. private static long product = 1;

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to play with streams and it is close to your idea - to load everything to array and then sum:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int number;
        String numberString;

        numberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer or 0 to quit: ");
        number = Integer.parseInt(numberString);

        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        while(number != 0)
        {
            // here is just adding to ArrayList
            numbers.add(number);

            numberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer or 0 to quit: ");
            number = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
        }
        sums(numbers);
        System.exit(0);

    } // End of main() method.

    // Write sums() method here.
    public static void sums(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
        int sum = numbers
                .stream()
                .mapToInt(i -> i.intValue())
                .sum();
        System.out.println(String.format("Sum: %s", sum));
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking into this but I have to use Java 7 by force. This is similar to the idea I was working on when approaching my problem. Thank you for sharing.